# How to get table column index using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, indexing, html-table

I have adequate knowledge about jQuery and its usage but today i got into a trouble of getting the column index of matching label inside `th` element of `table` using jQuery. I want to get the index of `th` element having `label` text as **Mobile**. The index should be 2 in this case. I am getting the actual index but this is not the correct way of doing it. So i want to know why jQuery is not giving me the right index using `index()` method.

I have also written the [JS Fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/furqansafdar/DHkb4/2/) for this.

**jQuery**

```js
var elem = $('#tbl th');
var rIndex;
alert('Length : ' + elem.length);
var index = elem.filter(
    function(index){
        var labelText = $(this).find('label').text();        
        //alert(index + ' - ' + labelText);
        var result = labelText == 'Mobile';
        if (result)
            rIndex = index;
        return result;
    }).index();
alert("jQuery Index : " + index);
alert("Actual Index : " + rIndex);
```

**HTML**

```html
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Application No.</label></th>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Name</label></th>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Mobile</label></th>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Gender</label></th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

This will give you real index
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DHkb4/4/)**

```
elem.each(function(){
    if( $(this).find('label').text()=='Mobile') {
        alert(elem.index(this));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use rowIndex for row index and event object to get the cellIndex.

```
this.rowIndex //for row index
e.toElement.cellIndex //for column index
```

Fiddle below

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/y49hsqem/)

Answer (score 2):

For Some Ref:

```
$('input').blur(function() {
    var total_qty = 0;
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    var col = $td.parent().children("td").index($td);
    $('table tbody tr').each(function() {
        var $td = $(this).find('td:eq('+col+')');
        var qty = $td.find('input').val();
        if(qty != '') total_qty += qty;
    });
    console.log(total_qty);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#tbl').find('th').each(function($index){
    if($(this).children('label').html() == 'Mobile')
        alert($index);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

"If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements."

source http://api.jquery.com/index/

Below is an example of how to use index() to achieve the result you're looking for. Please note I added an id to the column you want the index of just to make the example more simple, feel free to select in in anyway you desire.

```
<table id="tbl">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Application No.</label></th>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Name</label></th>
        <td></td>
        <th id="mobile"><label>Mobile</label></th>
        <td></td>
        <th><label>Gender</label></th>
    </tr>
</table>

var elem = $('#tbl th');
var rIndex;
alert('Length : ' + elem.length);
var index = elem.filter(
    function(index){
        var labelText = $(this).find('label').text();        
        //alert(index + ' - ' + labelText);
        var result = labelText == 'Mobile';
        if (result)
            rIndex = index;
        return result;
    }).index();
alert("jQuery Index : " + index);
alert("Actual Index : " + rIndex);


correctIndex = $('th').index($('#mobile'))

alert("Used correctly :" + correctIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Index function returns the index based upon the list you provide. In this case the outcome of the filter.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do it is use .prevAll() on the td and then on its parent tr:

```
var row = $td.closest('tr').prevAll().length;
var col = $td.prevAll().length;
```

(`$td being the td elem you are checking`)

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/g5s0ex20/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table th').each(function(i){
    if($($(this).find('label')).html() == "Name"{
       console.log("position= " + i); return false;
    }
});
```